# ListView recycling with multiple types of views

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently working on a quite simply ListView with up to 2 different view types. In order too make everything smooth i try to recycle views. My code is by now:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType (int position){
    if(mHasBefore&&position==0){
        return TYPE_PAGER;
    }else if(mHasNext&&position==getCount()-1){
        return TYPE_PAGER;
    }else return TYPE_SCORE;
}
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount (){
    return 1+((mHasBefore==true||mHasNext==true)?1:0);
}@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("outa","View: pos: "+position+ " . "+getItemViewType(position)+" - "+getViewTypeCount());
    if(getItemViewType(position)==TYPE_SCORE)return getScoreView(position,convertView,parent);
    else return getPagerView(position,convertView,parent);
}
protected View getPagerView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.listitem_highscore_pager, null);}}
protected View getScoreView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
    if (convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.listitem_highscore, null);}}
```

Basicly it should show a different view on the last item but it still shows the default item even if the LogCat states it is not TYPE_SCORE in getView(). Hence convertView does provide a recycled view. Do I do something wrong or is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Listview with different layout for each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777272/android-listview-with-different-layout-for-each-row)

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
    private static final int TYPE_PAGER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_PAGER = 1;
    private static final int VIEW_COUNT = 2;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount (){
            return VIEW_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;
                ViewHolder2 holder2;
                int type = getItemViewType(position);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder2 = new ViewHolder2();
                    switch(type){
                    case TYPE_SCORE:
                        Log.i(TAG, "ConvertView type1");
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_highscore, null);
                        convertView.setTag(R.layout.listitem_highscore, holder);
                    break;
                    case TYPE_PAGER:
                        Log.i(TAG, "ConvertView type0");
                        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_highscore_pager, null);
                        convertView.setTag(R.layout.listitem_highscore_pager, holder2);
                    break;

                    }
}

                } else{
                    // Get the ViewHolder back to get fast access to the TextViews
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(R.layout.baseadapter);
                    holder2 = (ViewHolder2)convertView.getTag(R.layout.baseadapter1);
                }


                switch(type){
            case TYPE_SCORE:
               holder.holderText.setText("type1");
            break;
            case TYPE_PAGER:
               holder2.holder2Text.setText("type2");
            break;

            }
    }
```

View holders:

```
 static class ViewHolder {
      //Place your views here for example:
      TextView holderText;

  }

 static class ViewHolder2{
       TextView holder2Text;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getItemViewType()` has to return stable values. IOW, for `position` of `0`, `getItemViewType()` has to *always* return `TYPE_PAGER`, not based on some other `mHasBefore` value.

If you wish to have unstable values, you will need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` every time you would need to change the value. IOW, if you toggle `mHasBefore` from whatever it was originally, you would need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and again if you change `mHasBefore` back to its original value.

Answer (score -2):

What about using a HeaderView and a FooterView on the ListView ?

That way, you haven't to handle multiple types...