# Multiple type of views in Recycler View not setting correctly

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have two array list and want to set the adapter so that it looks like below screen one. But when I am setting adapter I am getting view like second screen. This is my code of Adapter:

```
public class ItemArrayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
final int VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE = 0;
final int VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final String TAG = "ItemArrayAdapter";
Context context;
ArrayList<BeforLoginDao.Article> mArticleList;
ArrayList<BeforLoginDao.Quiz> mQuizList;
int i=0;

public ItemArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<BeforLoginDao.Quiz> mQuizList, ArrayList<BeforLoginDao.Article> mArticleList ){
    this.context = context;
    this.mArticleList = mArticleList;
    this.mQuizList = mQuizList;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    View itemView;
    if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE){
        itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_layout,parent,false);
        return new ArticleViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    else if(viewType == VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE){
        itemView= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.quiz,parent,false);
        return new QuizViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position){
    Log.e(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: " +position);
    if(viewHolder instanceof ArticleViewHolder){
        ((ArticleViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(mArticleList.get(position));
    }
    else if(viewHolder instanceof QuizViewHolder){
        ((QuizViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(mQuizList.get(position - mArticleList.size()));
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount(){
    return mArticleList.size() + mQuizList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position){
    Log.e(TAG, "getItemViewType: " +position );
    if(position < mArticleList.size()){
        return VIEW_TYPE_MESSAGE;
    }

    if(position - mArticleList.size() < mQuizList.size()){
        return VIEW_TYPE_IMAGE;
    }

    return -1;
}

public class ArticleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView mTitle, mTag1, mTag2  ;
    ImageView mImageView;
    public ArticleViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTitle =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_article_title);
        mTag1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_article_tag1);
        mTag2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_article_tag2);
        mImageView=itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_article);
    }

    public void populate(BeforLoginDao.Article chatWrapper){
       mTitle.setText(chatWrapper.articleTitle.toString());
       mTag1.setText(chatWrapper.subtag1);
       mTag2.setText(chatWrapper.subtag2);

    }
}

public class QuizViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView tvQuizTitle, tvQuizTag1, tvQuizTag2 ;
    public QuizViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvQuizTitle =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quiz_title);
        tvQuizTag1 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_quiz_tag1);
        tvQuizTag2=itemView.findViewWithTag(R.id.tv_quiz_tag2);



    }

    public void populate(BeforLoginDao.Quiz imageDataWrapper){
        Log.e(TAG, "ViewHolderTwo: " +imageDataWrapper.toString()  );
      tvQuizTitle.setText(imageDataWrapper.quizTitle);
      tvQuizTag1.setText(imageDataWrapper.quiz_subtag1);
    }
}
```

}

To solve this error I also checked many solution on SO.
Ref: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17107927/listview-recycling-with-multiple-types-of-views)

Below is screen one and screen two. Screen one that I need, Screen two that I am getting.

[image]      [image]

Comment: check this [Create a RecyclerView with multiple view from layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53779566/7666442)

Comment: show the layout and place where you're setting to recyclerview

Comment: from Your Screen1, it looks like You want Article view on Odd position (1,3,5 ...) & Quiz view on Even position (2,4,6 ...). am I right ? then on getItemViewType, perform position % 2 to set Article view, else Quiz view

Comment: @SolaimanHossain Yes you got my point. Now I am getting arrayindexout of boud exception on scrolling towards bottom on 6 position.

Comment: ((QuizViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(mQuizList.get(position - mArticleList.size())); may be this should be like this ((QuizViewHolder) viewHolder).populate(mQuizList.get(position));

Comment: I have to change in some code but your suggestion working thanks.

Comment: hi @AskNilesh can uou help me here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74052139/facing-the-missing-element-issue-in-multi-view-type-in-recyclerview